# twitter typeahead for large data

Tags: javascript, performance, twitter-typeahead

What is the best way to use twitter typeahead for large amounts of data(say 1M)?

I see that there is remote option which gets data from the database directly. What is the best way to index the suggestions and how to cache them ?